# KRDC Gives Error for IP Local IP Address?

Tags: networking, server, kubuntu, 18.04, kde

I'm using KDE's Remote Desktop Client (KDRC) to connect to a computer in the basement.

Here is the output of `ip a` on the terminal downstairs.

[image: ip a]These appear to be addresses on the private network. None of them work in the KDRC window. They all bounce back with an error message saying `server not found`.

I'm inexperienced with KRDC. Is this an error on my part? Is there something I'm missing (Set up before connecting to the desktop downstairs?)

Comment: I only see one IP on that system on the private network.  `192.168.1.20`  Did you setup some sort of RDP server on the basement computer?  Possibly `xrdp`?

Comment: ^ This is probably #1 question - is there software installed on that basement computer to accept the connection. #2 is it visible on the network otherwise? (e.g. `ping 192.168.1.20` ).

Comment: @Terrance Not that I know of. I would have thought that it would be acceptable to have `KRDC` installed on both computers. I'm guessing that I have to set up an RDP server or something similar?

Comment: @Moilleadóir Ping was successful to `192.168.1.20`.

Comment: Unfortunately `krdc` is only a remote desktop client that I am aware of.  [xrdp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp) is a server for remote desktop protocol.

Comment: I know almost nothing about KDE, but in the Gnomish world you need to enable access in settings - is there something similar?